# AWS Lambda: Variable value from one execution is preserved and used by subsequent run

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, variables, aws-lambda

I have a problem aws lambda python. 
I have a variable defined in a lambda layer and when we have multiple calls to that code , the variable value from one execution is preserved and used by subsequent run.

Is there any way to make each lambda execution to reset all variable and not to use any variable value from previous run.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this is nothing to do with Lambda Layers and everything to do with [container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) (a performance feature of Lambda). Anything declared outside your handler function will persist across warm restarts.

For more, see [AWS Lambda Execution Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html).

One possible way to test for cold/warm startup, and reset an environment, is as follows:

```
import json
import logging

cache = {}
cold_start = True

def handler(event, context):
    global cold_start

    if cold_start:
        print("Cold start")
        cold_start = False
    else:
        print("Warm start, reset cache")
        cache = {}

    # do work here
    cache['name'] = 'Jason'
    cache['age'] = 27
```

Comment: Or, go the extra mile and avoid stateful Lambda functions